# Set today as a start day of the month in date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker

Can we set the start date of the month to today and the end to that date in next month.

For example: today is 01/28/2013
Calendar should display from 01/28/2013 to 02/27/2013

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

try this (-1D to get 27 of next month otherwise it would be same of today date):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0, maxDate: "+1M -1D" });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.I don't want to display all the past date just display from current date to that date of next month.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can:

Do this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txtDate").datepicker({ minDate: 0, maxDate: '+1M', numberOfMonths:1 });
});
```

Comment: Where in the documentation did you find the "+1M"?

Comment: http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/10/set-date-range-to-one-month-in-jquery.html  I refered this!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it is not really what i want. I don't want display all past date and click on next button to go next month. I just want to display all date starting from the date of today to that date of next month.